# How to fix query selectors (DOM) and event listeners?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, event-listener

I am currently doing Angela Yu's web development course. However, there is one thing that I am stuck on. At section 13 she introduces Event Listeners. However, when I try to click the "W" button, no alert box pops up. I know the JavaScript file is properly connected with the HTML file since I can make a simple alert pop up when I just write alert("Hello World");. Also, when I run the completed files for this section, it works perfectly. I am just stuck on this small step.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListsener("click", handleClick);

function handleClick() {
  alert("I got clicked!");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
<h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
<div class="set">
  <button class="w drum">w</button>
  <button class="a drum">a</button>
  <button class="s drum">s</button>
  <button class="d drum">d</button>
  <button class="j drum">j</button>
  <button class="k drum">k</button>
  <button class="l drum">l</button>
</div>


<script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<footer>
  Made with ❤️ in London.
</footer>
```

Comment: `addEventListsener` — That isn't how you spell Listener. Look at the Console in your browser's developer tools. It would have highlighted the problem being there.

Comment: `document.querySelector()` only returns the first match. Use `document.querySelectorAll()` and loop over the result to add listeners to all the buttons.

Comment: @mplungjan Thats another solution.

Comment: I think you will find [my updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69257839/295783) works for you. It will click the button with the letter you type

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change `.addEventListsener` to `.addEventListener` . Your rest of the code is correct.

If you want to apply event for key press like `W` `shift` `up` `down`... then use something like this in snippet below

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == "87") {
    document.querySelector("button").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    window.alert("W got clicked!");
  } else{document.querySelector("button").style.backgroundColor = "";}
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
<h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
<div class="set">
  <button class="w drum">w</button>
  <button class="a drum">a</button>
  <button class="s drum">s</button>
  <button class="d drum">d</button>
  <button class="j drum">j</button>
  <button class="k drum">k</button>
  <button class="l drum">l</button>
</div>


<script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<footer>
  Made with ❤️ in London.
</footer>
```

Comment: See this for various `keycode` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: keyCode is deprecated and hard to read, and why not [click the button instead of making it red](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69257839/295783)

Comment: Yes , it is a good choice to click but user already know the method , as his code has only spelling mistake so I suggested another method that can be taken into consideration

Answer (score 1):

Spelling addEventListener correctly aside

Please delegate

Click in the snippet before typing

```js
const set = document.querySelector(".set");
const keys = set.querySelectorAll('.drum');

const handleClick = e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains('drum')) {
    console.log(tgt.textContent, "got clicked!");
  }
};

const keyArr = [...keys].map(key => key.textContent.toUpperCase());

const handleKey = e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const key = e.code.slice(-1)
  const index = keyArr.indexOf(key)
  if (index != -1) keys[index].click()
};


set.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
document.addEventListener("keypress", handleKey);
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
<h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
<div class="set">
  <button class="w drum">w</button>
  <button class="a drum">a</button>
  <button class="s drum">s</button>
  <button class="d drum">d</button>
  <button class="j drum">j</button>
  <button class="k drum">k</button>
  <button class="l drum">l</button>
</div>


<script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<footer>
  Made with ❤️ in London.
</footer>
```

Comment: can you tell about `e.target;`  `e.code` , know that target is something targeted but how it works as seen in many places like `.indexOf` search for the word inside a given data . How does `e.target` works

Comment: @Rana So `e` is the variable I use for the passed event that we are listening to. keypress or click. The e.target what actually triggered the event, like the 'a' key - that would make e.code = 'KeyA' (instead of e.keyCode 97 which is harder to remember)

I make an array with all your letters and index my way into it, then I know which button to press because it is the second (index 1 - starts from 0)

Comment: does this `e.target` works same as `this` keyword or some difference is there

Comment: In this case no. I ruined `this` by using an arrow function instead of `function` which sets `this` in the function

Comment: Since I am delegating, I do not need `this` but DO need `e.target` instead

Comment: In vast scenario does these `e.target` and `this` works same . And what does delegating mean

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events Bedtime here